# SSIS extract value from Data Profiling Task result

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I requested a `Column Null Ratio Profile request` in SSIS for one of my sample table for testing purpose, I got the `Inclusion Report` in XML format without any problem, but how could I utilize the `<NullCount>` from the report for each of selected column? Or how could I extract the null population information for all the columns requested?

Below is the part of the XML report generated from the task:

```
   <Profiles>
      <ColumnNullRatioProfile ProfileRequestID="NullRatioReq" IsExact="true">
        <DataSourceID>{AD39E650-3865-4703-89AB-B9D8D7A83CB3}</DataSourceID>
        <Table DataSource="njpp-dm02" Database="Reporting" Schema="dbo" Table="Error" RowCount="6" />
        <Column Name="Error" SqlDbType="VarChar" MaxLength="-1" Precision="255" Scale="255" LCID="1033" CodePage="0" IsNullable="true" StringCompareOptions="0" />
        <NullCount>0</NullCount>
      </ColumnNullRatioProfile>
      <ColumnNullRatioProfile ProfileRequestID="NullRatioReq" IsExact="true">
        <DataSourceID>{AD39E650-3865-4703-89AB-B9D8D7A83CB3}</DataSourceID>
        <Table DataSource="njpp-dm02" Database="Reporting" Schema="dbo" Table="Error" RowCount="6" />
        <Column Name="Runtime" SqlDbType="DateTime" MaxLength="0" Precision="255" Scale="255" LCID="-1" CodePage="0" IsNullable="true" StringCompareOptions="0" />
        <NullCount>0</NullCount>
      </ColumnNullRatioProfile>
    </Profiles>
```

From the above XML code, as you could see from the `<Column Name = "Error"...>`I believe the `<NullCount>` followed by it is the value that I need to extract (and it is a correct result).

I tried below C# code to handle that XML report, but it throws me the error without any useful information, and I am not sure if I have multiple columns, how to get or what is the correct way to show each pair of result.

**C# Code:**

```
//code before

using System.XML;

//code after

public void Main()
        {


            String InclusionRpt = Dts.Variables["User::InclusionRpt"].Value.ToString();

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

            xml.LoadXml(InclusionRpt);

            XmlNodeList nodelist = xml.GetElementsByTagName("NullCount");

            int i = 0;

            for (i = 0; i <= 1;  i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)    
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("The total number of Null found in \"Error\" is " + nodelist[i].InnerText);
                    } 
                if (i == 1)
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("The total number of Null found in \"RunTime\" is " + nodelist[i].InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

So again, question in short, how could I show the null population for those two columns (Error, and Runtime)? Thanks :)

Comment: What is the error that your existing code returns?

Comment: @TabAlleman, just says `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`, but I located the issue, that happened because of `XmlNodeList nodelist = xml.GetElementsByTagName("NullCount");` I think that is not correct for retrieving this tag

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the script after the `LoadXML` line, and look at the value of `xml`, does it contain the expected XML?

Comment: @TabAlleman, the xml is good, but I cannot extra the value from it. And I cannot debug it from VS because of VSTA issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the example in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx), your existing code only has a couple of small difference from the sample code they provide:

1. `xml.LoadXml(InclusionRpt);` -- the MSDN example uses `.Load()` instead of `.LoadXml`.   I also question whether naming your variable `xml` could be a problem due to it being a reserved word.
2. `nodelist[i].InnerText` -- MSDN uses `.InnerXml` instead of `.InnerText`.  I don't think this should be a problem, but it is a difference from the sample MSDN code.

Because your differences from the sample code are so minor, I suspect it is most likely that the document you are attempting to load either isn't loading at all, or that the contents of that document aren't what you say they are.

If you can't use the Debugger, I would try using a MessageBox or some other programmatic means to show the contents of `xml` after it is loaded.

Comment: Thank @Tab Allenman for following up this question, you're right, the full inclusion xml did not get loaded correctly, and I just want to mention few points here, it should use `.LoadXml` method for the `XML` text; the variable name `xml` is good here; last but not least, should extract the text using `.InnerText` :)